# Hamachi Gateway under Linux

Tags: linux, networking, hamachi

Has anybody successfully gotten Hamachi working on a Linux server working as a gateway? Any help getting that setup?

I'm in a dorm room (so I am pretty much forced to use Hamachi instead of OpenVPN) and I have a router in my room setup with my desktop, a RaspberryPi, and a few network devices (printer and a NAS.) I'd like to setup Hamachi on the Pi to serve as a gateway into my dorm network so I could access the devices elsewhere.

I have Hamachi installed on the Pi (running Debian,) but when I use the Hamachi web site to setup a Gateway network between my RaspberryPi and Laptop, it just doesn't want to work. The Hamachi client on my laptop shows the Pi having address "0.0.0.0" and I can't ping the Pi pr access any of the network resources.

Here are the results of ifconfig on the Pi:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:c8:ce:e0
          inet addr:192.168.1.134  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ba27:ebff:fec8:cee0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1584 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:950 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:207635 (202.7 KiB)  TX bytes:121937 (119.0 KiB)

ham0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 7a:79:05:0b:32:bc
          inet addr:5.11.50.188  Bcast:5.255.255.255  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: 2620:9b::50b:32bc/96 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::7879:5ff:fe0b:32bc/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1404  Metric:1
          RX packets:647 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:85 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500
          RX bytes:100175 (97.8 KiB)  TX bytes:11832 (11.5 KiB)

ham1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:23:c3:0b:32:bc
          inet6 addr: fe80::223:c3ff:fe0b:32bc/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1404  Metric:1
          RX packets:22 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500
          RX bytes:1320 (1.2 KiB)  TX bytes:468 (468.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

- eth0 is the interface to my network.
- ham0 is the interface Hamachi permanently has connected. This is present before the Pi is a member of any Hamachi network.
- ham1 is the interface that appeared when I created the Hamachi Gateway network.
- lo - Loopback

Here's what's in the routing table:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
5.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 ham0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One question, if you setup a gateway network and made this Pi machine a gateway, the interfaces should include something like ham-br0 or so, which is a bridge interface. So I suspect you didn't make the pi machine a gateway on the web.

Comment: Actually, the routing table reveals the problem without any shroud: your default gateway has remained your local gateway, 192.168.1.1, while you have local connection to the 5.0.0.0 net via the ham0 IF. A properly configured VPN should have a default gateway which belongs to some remote server, plus instructions to forward all connection requests to the remote gateway via your local gateway 192.168.1.1. So the configurtion is, at best, incomplete.